# WPF accesses only single instance of derived class with dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a simple class derived from Button with a dependency property:

```
public sealed class CircleButton : Button
{
    public Visual Visual
    {
        get { return (Visual)GetValue(VisualProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VisualProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Visual", typeof(Visual), typeof(CircleButton));
}
```

I have the following style for the CircleButton:

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls1:CircleButton}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource CircleButtonRectangleStyle}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
</Style>
```

The rectangle style referenced in the CircleButton style is defined as:

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButtonRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls1:CircleButton}}, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls1:CircleButton}}, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls1:CircleButton}}, Path=Visual}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Finally, my XAML defines three CircleButton instances:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <controls:CircleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30.0" Height="30.0" 
                    Style="{DynamicResource CircleButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Add}" ToolTip="Add new product filter." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                                   Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_add}"/>
            <controls:CircleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30.0" Height="30.0" 
                    Style="{DynamicResource CircleButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Remove}" ToolTip="Remove product filter." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                                   Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_minus}"/>
            <controls:CircleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30.0" Height="30.0" 
                    Style="{DynamicResource CircleButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Remove}" ToolTip="Remove product filter." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                                   Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_music}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

All three buttons display, but only the last in the sequence has an image (it is the correct one).  This occurs no matter how many buttons I add.

Anyone see what I'm missing and what I need to do to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious, but in fact you're only defining one instance of `VisualBrush`. There will be exactly one copy of the content of that `Setter.Value` element. Each time it gets added to one of your circle buttons, it gets yanked out of the previous one.

Try applying a template instead, and apply that visual brush to an element in the template. Elements in a template *are* created individually every time the template is applied.

Now, you can't apply a `ControlTemplate` to a `Rectangle`. But you can apply lots of templates to lots of things, so no big deal.

This might work. `Button` is a subclass of `ContentControl` so it's got a `ContentTemplate` property, which is instantiated to display whatever you put in the `Button`'s `Content` property. This use is a little funny because it doesn't display the `Content` -- but you're not using `Content`.

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls1:CircleButton}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle
                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls1:CircleButton}}, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}}"
                    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls1:CircleButton}}, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}}"
                    Fill="White"
                    >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls1:CircleButton}}, Path=Visual}"/>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But you know what type `ContentControl.Content` is? It's `Object`. You can stuff anything in there, and the `ContentTemplate` can do whatever it likes with whatever it finds. I bet this would work just fine, and might save you having to write that `CircleButton` subclass at all:

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle
                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}}"
                    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}}"
                    Fill="White"
                    >
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Content}"/>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- ... -->

<Button 
    Style="{DynamicResource CircleButtonStyle}" 
    Command="{Binding Remove}" 
    ToolTip="Remove product filter." 
    Content="{DynamicResource appbar_music}"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, let me look into this.  Rectangle doesn't appear to allow a ControlTemplate definition, but maybe there's a way to do this directly within the CircleButton style.

Comment: @ket You don't need to template Rectangle. The content item you template can be anything that can be templated, since you're replacing its content anyway. `ContentControl` would be fine.

Comment: @ket Updated with a `Style` that might do the job.

Comment: Awesome - that worked!  Thanks so much.  I could've spent a lot of time trying to figure that out.

Comment: @ket Glad to hear it!