# Make Polygon resource unique

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF accesses only single instance of derived class with dependency property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207572/wpf-accesses-only-single-instance-of-derived-class-with-dependency-property)

I defined a Polygon as a resource of my UserControl in the XAML file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Polygon x:Key="MyPolygon">
        <Polygon.Points>
            ...
        </Polygon.Points>
    </Polygon>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and would like to create multiple (but individual) instances of this element and add them to a Canvas.

```
Polygon polygon = (Polygon) this.Resources["MyPolygon"];
// ...
canvas.Children.Add(polygon);
```

When adding the polygon a second time by running the above code repeatedly, the following error is thrown:

> Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.

Possible solutions are:

- Cloning the Polygon, which isn't the most elegant way
- Generating the Polygon from code

Is there any better solution which maybe makes use of the Resources property (or a sort of instantiable Polygon)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "instantiatable polygon" in XAML would be a template with a `Polygon` in it. Wherever you need the polygon to be, put a `ContentControl` there and apply the template to it.

And life is a lot easier if you do all of this in XAML, not code behind.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyPolygonTemplate">
        <Polygon>
            <Polygon.Points>
            ...
            </Polygon.Points>
        </Polygon>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <ContentControl 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyPolygonTemplate}" 
            />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

If you need to create an arbitrary number of them, use an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` for its [`ItemsPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx), and put a `Polygon` in the [`ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) for the [`ItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). To populate the `ItemsControl`, you'd bind its `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` property of your viewmodel. The collection would contain whatever data item objects your polygon things are meant to visually represent. If you need ten polygons flying around, put ten thingies in the collection and bingo, there they are. Yank one out and the UI will show only the remaining nine. To position them, bind `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` to appropriate properties of the data item class (which must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)) (you might have to apply those via [an `ItemContainerStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx); I haven't done much with `Canvas`).

You don't actually have to use the `ContentControl`'s `Content` property if there's no need. But you could use `Content` to pass the `Polygon` different sets of `Points` from a data item class, if you wanted to.

This is a duplicate of a common question; [I answered it yesterday too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207572/wpf-accesses-only-single-instance-of-derived-class-with-dependency-property).

Comment: Thank you very much!
How would I add an instance of that Polygon template to the Canvas without Binding?

Comment: @xoxox Without binding, that should work just as in my exams xaml above. Put in a ContentControl with that for its ContentTemplate

Comment: Sorry, I meant in code: I have the Polygon template as `DataTemplate` object and would like to apply a fill style etc. to that Polygon. So how can I retrieve a unique Polygon from  that `DataTemplate` object?

Comment: @xoxox You can apply the style in XAML. If you want the polygons to differ from each other, you would bind properties of your data item class. What you want to do is unnecessarily painful and difficult. You'll be fighting against WPF instead of letting it help you. When you fight against WPF, you generally lose.

Comment: Alright, I'll go with binding and posted a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There also is [`x:Shared`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)`="false"`.

> When set to **false**, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

Comment: One of the lesser known WPF things, glad to help :)

Comment: IntelliSense does not recognize it though. (VS 2012)

Comment: That might be one of the reasons. IntelliSense is not *The Truth* in any case.